# Android: Comparing handler message

Tags: android

I'm comparing handler messages to determine what to do depending on the message:
But somehow when the message is "1" the comparing still lists m == "1" as false how so?

[image]

Comment: you should use `Message#what` field for those purposes, the docs say: *User-defined message code so that the recipient can identify what this message is about. Each Handler has its own name-space for message codes, so you do not need to worry about yours conflicting with other handlers.*

Comment: and if you are using `obj` for passing the data you should use `Message#obtain(Handler h, int what, Object obj)` or `Handler#obtainMessage(int what, Object obj)` to get the `Message` you want to send

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing if both objects share the same memory address. While you should be comparing the content of both objects.

Solution: use `String.equals` to compare the content of your String values.

```
if("1".equals(m)){

}
```

**Note 1:** For primitive types (int, double, float, short and byte) `==` will work because the real values are compared instead of the memory address. For Objects (non-primitives) `==` always compares the memory address of both Objects.

**Note 2:** @pskink made a very useful comment, you should indeed use `Message.what` instead of `Message.obj`. `Message.obj` is useful to transfer the actual data needed (within the same Process) but not to identify the message itself.

Answer (score 1):

your if condition should be like this

```
if(m==1) //is for int

if(m.equals("1")) //is for string
```